# React getting two issues width compoment Select option

Tags: reactjs, loops

I'm getting two issue some strange, I have this form:

```
    import { SelectOption } from "../../../component/select/SelectOption"

    
    const Form = () => {
        const [selectState, setSelectState] = useState(0);
        const [selectCity, setSelectCity] = useState(0);
        const [listStates, setListStates] = useState([{}]);
        const [listCity, setListCity] = useState([{}]);
    
        const loadListStates = () => { 
            axios.request({
                /*configuration request with token*/
            })
            .then((response) => {
                const newStruct = response.data.map((e)=>{ return { 'id': e.id, 'name': e.fullName }});
                setListStates( newStruct )
            })  
            .catch((error) => {
            }); 
        }
    
        const loadListCity = () => { 
            axios.request({
                /*configuration request with token*/
            })
            .then((response) => {
                const newStruct = response.data.map( (e) => {return { 'id': e.id, 'name': e.fullName }} );
                setListCity( newStruct );
            })
            .catch((error) => {
            }); 
        }
    
        loadListStates();
        loadListCity();
    
        return(
            <Div>
                <SelectDiv>
                    <SelectOption    
                        key={1}
                        value={selectState}
                        setValue={setSelectState}
                        text="Select one"
                        list={listStates}                                        
                        borderRadious="10px"
                        width="20rem"                                       
                    /> 
    
                    <SelectOption    
                        key={1}
                        value={selectCity}
                        setValue={setSelectCity}
                        text="Select one"
                        list={listCity}                                        
                        borderRadious="10px"
                        width="20rem"                                       
                    /> 
                </SelectDiv>
            </Div>
        )
    }

    export default Form;
```

and my compent select is:

```
import { useState  } from 'react'; 
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import { Colors } from '../../const/colors';
import { Fonts } from "../../const/fonts";

export const SelectOption = ({ key, value, setValue, text, list, width, borderRadious}) => {

    const handleChange = (event) => { 
        setValue(event.target.value);
    };

    return(
        <FormControl>
            <Select
                key={key}           
                value={value}
                onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}
                displayEmpty
                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Without label' }} 
                defaultValue=""
                style={{
                    textDecoration: 'none',
                    width: width? width : '200px',
                    height: '40px',
                    top: '0.31px',
                    borderRadius: borderRadious? borderRadious : '5px',
                    border: '0',
                    padding: '11px, 20px, 11px, 20px',
                    backgroundColor: Colors.backgroundElement,
                    font: Fonts.Poppins                                       
                }} 
                  
                MenuProps={{
                    PaperProps: {
                      sx: {
                        "& .MuiMenuItem-root:hover": {
                          opacity: 1
                        },
                        "& .MuiMenuItem-root.Mui-selected": {
                            opacity: 1
                        },
                        "& .MuiMenuItem-root": {
                            backgroundColor: Colors.backgroundElement,
                            font: Fonts.Poppins, 
                            opacity: 0.5
                        },
                        "& .css-6hp17o-MuiList-root-MuiMenu-list":{
                            backgroundColor: Colors.backgroundElement
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }}
            >
                <MenuItem defaultValue="" key={0}>
                    {text}
                </MenuItem>
                { 
                    list?.map((value)=>{
                        return(
                            <MenuItem 
                                key={value.id} 
                                value={value.id} 
                            >
                                {value.name}
                            </MenuItem>
                        )
                    }) 
                }
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    )
}
```

so, the error that I'm getting is when I'm going to check the console of my chrome devtools I'm getting an infinity loop, why?

I was checking it, so I remove on my `Form` the component `SelectOption` and the infinity loop was not shown in console anymore.

so, what's wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Every time* `<Form>` renders, it does this:

```
loadListStates();
loadListCity();
```

These operations interally update state:

```
setListStates( newStruct );
//...
setListCity( newStruct );
```

Updating state triggers a re-render.  In this case that re-render invokes those operations.  Which update state.  Which trigger a re-render.  Which invokes those operations.  Etc.  Etc.

Never update state in the rendering of a component.  I *suspect* you only want to perform those operations when the component *first* loads, which you can do with `useEffect()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  loadListStates();
  loadListCity();
}, []);
```

Note the empty array at the end.  An empty dependency array tells `useEffect` to execute only once when the component loads.  Omitting the array entirely tells is to execute on every render (which you don't want here, it would be the same problem).  Adding any dependencies to the array would execute the effect any time one of those dependencies changes between renders.

Comment: hmmm..... so, I just need added `useEffect` function on my component `Form`